# LaunchScreen working in iPhoneX simulator but not displaying in real iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9, launch-screen

I added LaunchScreen.storyboard to simple sample project. In simulator its working perfect in all simulators...even its working in iPhoneX simulator. But when I run in real iPhone 6, white screen displayed.

Here is Sample Project : https://app.box.com/s/bxn8zjbmrvm91f950xxsrjzbjshcbbhx

[image]

**Updates** I just took another iPhone and same code worked perfect

Comment: Just downloaded the project — the launch screen is working on all simulators and a real device.

Comment: @nathan in my iPhone 6 (iOS 11.0.1) it shows just white screen. In which device you tried ?

Comment: I used an iPhone 6 running iOS 11.0

Comment: iOS version ? mine iOS 11.0.1, Xcode 9

Comment: I think you should re-install the app, clean your Xcode project, etc.

Comment: @nathan just now I did clean and re-build...again it shows white screen instead of my splash screen. You did any changes ?

Comment: No changes, although you should set constraints on your image view in the launch storyboard.

Comment: @nathan please send me updated source that working in your device, post as answer, I can approve

Comment: I didn't make any changes besides modifying the signing so I could run it on my device.

Comment: your Xcode version ? your iOS version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155943/discussion-between-nathan-and-guru).